# Error during transfering Bytes xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I try to upload at least 30 pictures to a web server but my program catch errors.
They appear randomly, sometimes at the first image, sometimes third etc.

> {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs:3874 
>     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:1043 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

OR

> Read error: ssl=0x7e46332e08: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

I explain you the process : I got an array with image path and I created a loop to upload each image on my web server.

```
public async void LaunchImagesUpload()
{
   for (int i = startIndex; i < picturesToDisplay.Count; i++)
   {
       try
       {
          await UploadSinglePicture(i);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          if(e.Message.Equals("The operation was canceled."))
          {
              hasErrors = true;
          }
          else if(e.Message.Equals("Error while copying content to a stream."))
          {
              // Sometimes program goes here
              hasErrors = true;
          }
          else
          {
              // Sometimes program goes here
              currentPictureGrid.ActivateCancelledMode("error , retry please");
              hasErrors = true;
          }

       }
   }
```

}

Here is the http call

```
public static async Task<string> CreateUploadTask(string file, string id, string user_id, string user_login)
        {

            string requestResult = "";

            var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var image = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(file));
            image.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "file", FileName = "imageToUpload.jpeg" };
            image.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
            cont.Add(image);

            string id_level = id
            string uri = // private uri
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, cont);
                if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return "error";
                }

                requestResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("DATA FINAL" + requestResult);

            }

            return requestResult;

        }
```

How can I upload multiple image. Do I made a mistake. There is another way to uplad pictures thank's in advance

**UPDATE**
I used breakpoint to see when appear error and I added a handler.HttpSendProgress to see the transfer and error appear during transfer

Here is the nuew CreateUploadTask function

```
public static async Task<string> CreateUploadTask(string file, string vtour_id, string user_id, string user_login)
        {

            string requestResult = "";
            HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(file));
            await Task.Delay(500);
            fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "file", FileName = "imageToUpload.jpeg" };
            fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
            string boundary = "---8393774hhy37373773";
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
            {
                handler.HttpSendProgress += (s, e) =>
                {
// error is here because I display transfer and not all Bytes are transfered
                        float prog = (float)e.BytesTransferred / (float)File.OpenRead(file).Length;
                        prog = prog > 1 ? 1 : prog;
                        if (prog > .99)
                        {
                            currentPictureGrid.ActivateTreatmentMode();
                            Console.WriteLine("IMAGE IMPORT --------- Transfert -------- Mode 'en cours de traitement' activé");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("step 0");
                            byteTransferedBeforeBug = (float)e.BytesTransferred;
                            byteTotalBeforeBug = (float)File.OpenRead(file).Length;
                            currentPictureGrid.UpdateUploadRate((float)e.BytesTransferred, (float)File.OpenRead(file).Length);
                        }

                    };

                    formData.Add(fileStreamContent);
                    string id_level = (jsoncontent != null && jsoncontent.GetValue(currentPath.ToString())["floor"].ToString() != null ? jsoncontent.GetValue(currentPath.ToString())["floor"].ToString() : "0");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(MY_PRIVATE_URL, formData);
                    requestResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("DATA RESULT : " + requestResult);


            }

            return requestResult;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of internet programming.   Sometimes things don't work !   Also you should NOT create a new HttpClient for every connection (just reuse the same one for each use).  Also, you should await EVERY async function.

Comment: haha I agree with you, I'm novice with mobile development, 
I used to work on web development. I'm going to put a property called _client and I use this var but should I keep using (_client) {} or not. Thank you

Comment: I currently use await while I need to wait response

Comment: you can Encode in Base64 and send in body

Comment: Do you think that can resolve the problem because error seems to tell it's a "transport connection" connection. I will try it to be sure

Comment: Does the error still appear after you add the await?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I need to use await because I use ReadStringAsync. I think I have to use thread to download each image. I'm looking a video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXg9g56FS0k

Comment: Yes, I mean the error you get was caused by not using await. Once you find a solution, you can write it here:).

Comment: Thank you @JackHua-MSFT for your reply. I used thread but same result, so I made breakpoints and the error occured when I tranfer Byte to a stream. I mean the error doesn't appear during the use of HttpClient

Comment: Ok, it's hard for me to reproduce the problem on my side and I can't help much.  Also, I think you can consider to reduce the number of images you need to upload at the same time.

Comment: Thank's @JackHua-MSFT, I put a loop which is contains await upload function so there is just one upload at the same time but I noticed when I got a low connexion like 1 mbps indeed 2 or 3 mbps for upload i got an error

Comment: I mean you are creating 30 tasks in that loop and it maybe too much. Hope you can find a solution later.

Comment: How can I create 30 tasks because I put await in each Task, so it execute first, second etc ? I thought that was what was going on, tell if it's not the case

Comment: await is waiting the result, you are creating 30 tasks at that loop, they execute at the same time. See [csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Ok sorry @JackHua-MSFT I didn't know thank you. How can I execute one task by one, thank you for the link I will read as soon as possible

Comment: You can start a new one after the task is completed.

Comment: How can I verify that a task is completed ? I diddn't find

Comment: At the point you get the response.